# how to prevent component overflow when dragged down (bottom sheet)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bottom-sheet

the bottom sheet has buttons fixed in the bottom of scree, when bottom sheet is down dragged the button hide, but appear a overflow message, i used bottom draggable scrollable sheet but i get same error.
I need that when dragget to down the buttons hide without overflow message, i used a cliprect but not work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCh2k.gif)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _isDarkTheme = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark;
    _maxHeight = _maxHeight ?? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9;
    _initialHeight =
        widget.initialHeight ?? (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5);

    return Stack(children: [
      widget.mainContent,
      if (widget.enableBackdrop && _percentOpen > 0.1)
        Container(
          color: _overlayExpandableFoundations.backDropColor
              .withOpacity(_animation.value),
        ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onVerticalDragUpdate: _onVerticalDragUpdate,
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            curve: Curves.bounceIn,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 50),
            height: _overlayHeight ?? _initialHeight,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                _OverlayHeader(
                  key: headerKey,
                  showSwipeIndicator: widget.showSwipeIndicator,
                  overlayExpandableFoundations: _overlayExpandableFoundations,
                  isDarkTheme: _isDarkTheme,
                  title: widget.title,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: _overlayExpandableFoundations.overlayBackgroundLight,
                    child: ListView(
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          key: listItems,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: widget.children ?? [],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                _ButtonsSection(
                  key: _buttonsKey,
                  closeBtnLabel: widget.closeBtnLabel,
                  onClosedPressed: widget.onClosedPressed,
                  optionBtnLabel: widget.optionBtnLabel,
                  onOptionBtnPressed: widget.onOptionBtnPressed,
                  horizontalButtons: widget.horizontalButtons,
                  optionBtnEnable: widget.optionBtnEnable,
                  overlayExpandableFoundations: _overlayExpandableFoundations,
                  isDarkTheme: _isDarkTheme,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }

  void _onVerticalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails d) {
    double newHeight = (_overlayHeight ?? _initialHeight) - d.delta.dy;

    if (newHeight >= _initialHeight && newHeight <= _maxHeight!) {
      double expandableHeight = _maxHeight! - _initialHeight;
      double expandedHeight = newHeight - _initialHeight;
      _percentOpen = expandedHeight / expandableHeight;
      _animationCont.animateTo(_percentOpen);

      _overlayHeight = newHeight;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

i need that overflow message disappear

Comment: Can you try wrapping the Stack inside RepaintBoundry widget?

Comment: i try wrap in repaint bundary but the result is equal

Comment: can you simplify the snippet , most of them are unknown(custom)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you try setting different values to `height: _overlayHeight ?? _initialHeight,` and see if it goes away. If it does, you might want to tweek the logic to find container height.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the solution for not show bottom overflow message is using a SlideTransition component, they fix the problem.
The slide transition allow that contaniner move to bottom without show overflow message.
https://mobikul.com/transitions-in-flutter/

```
SlideTransition(
          position: _animation,
          child: Semantics(
            label: 'overlay',
            button: true,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onVerticalDragUpdate: _onVerticalDragUpdate,
              onTap: _toggleOverlay,
              child: Container(
                key: _overlayKey,
                margin: widget.enableMargin
                    ? const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: ThemeSpacing.SPACE_S_1)
                    : null,
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
                  maxHeight: getMaxHeightOverlay(context),
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: ThemeShadow.shadow03,
                  color: _isDarkTheme
                      ? _overlayExpandableFoundations.overlayBackgroundDark
                      : _overlayExpandableFoundations.overlayBackgroundLight,
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: ThemeRadius.RADIUS_3,
                    topRight: ThemeRadius.RADIUS_3,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    _OverlayHeader(
                      key: _overlayHeaderKey,
                      showSwipeIndicator: widget.showSwipeIndicator,
                      title: widget.title,
                      onClosedPressed: widget.onClosedPressed,
                      closeOverlay: _closeOverlay,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: ThemeSpacing.SPACE_S_2,
                        ),
                        child: ListView(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          children: widget.children ?? [],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    _ButtonsSection(
                      closeBtnLabel: widget.closeBtnLabel,
                      onClosedPressed: widget.onClosedPressed,
                      buttonLabel: widget.buttonLabel,
                      onButtonPressed: widget.onButtonPressed,
                      horizontalButtons: widget.horizontalButtons,
                      btnEnable: widget.btnEnable,
                      overlayExpandableFoundations:
                          _overlayExpandableFoundations,
                      closeOverlay: _closeOverlay,
                      isDarkTheme: _isDarkTheme,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: This answer could help more people if you explain in the answer how to do that, rather than just linking to another site, as linked pages often change, go offline, etc.